# Keeping arrow centered on the tip in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, javascript, center

I have a map where a user can add features or arrows to certain areas to *"mark"* the map. However, upon zooming in/out of the map, the arrow coordinates are centered for the center of the arrow, not the arrow tip.  How could this be fixed?

I think we are using this to set up the layers:

```js
_this.featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({ 
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: _this.features}) 
});
```

I should also clarify the arrows are font awesome arrows, so they are text.

They are styled like so:

```js
style = new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: _this.iconUnicodes[shape],
        font: 'normal ' + fontSize + ' FontAwesome',
        textBaseline: 'middle',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: color,
        }),
        rotation: rotation
    })
 });
```

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

I assume your arrow is in an `ol.Overlay` class. You can add the `positioning` attribute for this class like this:

```js
var overlay = new ol.Overlay(({
  element: document.getElementById('marker'),
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: { duration: 250 },
  positioning: 'bottom-center'
}));
```

You can define following positions:

```
'bottom-left', 'bottom-center', 'bottom-right', 'center-left', 'center-center', 'center-right', 'top-left', 'top-center', and 'top-right'.
```

By providing this property your arrow/marker should be placed correctly.

Comment: See my edits for clarification. @valentin

Comment: Where do you style your vector source in your code? There should be a class named ol.style.Something. You can also check the API documentation: [ol API] (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.style.html

Comment: Here: style = new ol.style.Style({
                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                        text: _this.iconUnicodes[shape],
                        font: 'normal ' + fontSize + ' FontAwesome',
                        textBaseline: 'middle',
                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                          color: color,
                        }),
                        rotation: rotation
                    })
                });

Comment: Ok, maybe you should experiment with the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties of your ol.style.Text instance. Propably something like `offsetY: -5` or so.